# Ruby on Rails API how to soft delete an user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am able to soft delete an user from the main application.
Here are the details.

The user URL is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/4c7fa12c-3d58-480b-a823-6c67d6e7f0fe.json
```

Which is presenting a JSON result like this:

{"id":"4c7fa12c-3d58-480b-a823-6c67d6e7f0fe","name":"John","status":"Active","created_at":"2015-11-10T18:31:27.000+00:00","updated_at":"2015-11-10T18:38:20.000+00:00"}

I can do a soft delete by using an inactivation this way:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/4c7fa12c-3d58-480b-a823-6c67d6e7f0fe/inactivate
```

Here is my inactivate method in the users controller:

```
  def inactivate
    @user.update status: 'Inactive'
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

The result is shown when reload the user URL:

{"id":"4c7fa12c-3d58-480b-a823-6c67d6e7f0fe","name":"John","status":"Inactive","created_at":"2015-11-10T18:31:27.000+00:00","updated_at":"2015-11-10T19:29:58.000+00:00"}

Now my user is "Inactive".

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :wit_dims
  resources :wokas
  resources :posts
  resources :languages
  resources :users
  root :to => "home#index"

  resources :users do
    get 'inactivate', on: :member
  end

  match 'inactivate', to: 'users#inactivate', via: 'delete'

  #api
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]
      resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end

end
```

How I can change this routes file and the API users controller to make the same king of inactivation through the API? I want more than a trivial solution using a PUT to change status of the user from Active to Inactive.

Here is my main application users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :inactivate]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully inactivated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def inactivate
    @user.update status: 'Inactive'
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params[:user]
    end
end
```

Here is my API users controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    render(json: Api::V1::UserSerializer.new(@user).to_json)
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      render(
        json: Api::V1::UserSerializer.new(@user).to_json,
        status: 200,
        location: api_v1_user_path(@user.id)
      )
    else
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: @tbm.errors)
    end
  end

  def index
    users = User.all
    render(
      json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
        users,
        each_serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer,
        root: 'users'
      )
    )
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :status).delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil? }
    end
end
```

Basically I would like to be able to call an inactivate method through the API which is going to change the status from Active to Inactive, instead of physically deleting / destroying the user.

Comment: Huh? Why not do the same trick with `inactivate` action?

Comment: GET shouldn't change the db - `get 'inactivate', on: :member`.  Why do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do the same trick with the inactivation action through the API. I am ok how this is working from the main user controller. Need a hint how to do the same through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PUT and executed an updated on the status attribute to mark the user as Inactive.